# InDesign and transparency flatteners location

Tags: adobe-indesign, transparency

I have InDesign CS5 on Mac OS X 10.6.7 Snow Leopard, and created a new transparency flattener style called test1 as a preset.

I'm interested to know, where is my custom preset stored on Mac OS X; could I copy it to InDesign CS6 if I decide to install it so I don't have to re-create it?

I understand how to create them, that's not the issue, it's about *where* they are that I'm wondering.

All advice is much appreciated; I'm new to this area of InDesign.

Answer (score 1):

You can export or save those wherever you like on your hard drive. Do a "find" on your Mac and search for "test1" and you will see where you exported it to. Adobe themselves offers this advice:

> To export a preset to a separate file, click Save (InDesign) or Export
>   (Illustrator), specify a name and location, and then click Save.
>   Consider saving the preset outside of the application’s preferences
>   folder. That way, it won’t be lost if you delete your preferences. To
>   import presets from a file, click Load (InDesign) or Import
>   (Illustrator). Locate and select the file containing the preset you
>   want to load, and then click Open.

[You can see the full Adobe article here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6ea7a.html#WSC5B5B666-EDDD-4bab-A0B4-DBA6F6319E71).

Answer (score 0):

Dig around in these directories.

```
~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/
~/Library/Preferences/Adobe Illustrator CS5.1 Settings/
~/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign/
```